# Once munchkin lead tracking cookies are set marketo form not loading again

Tags: adobe, marketo

We are using Marketo form for lead capturing and using munchkin for lead tracking. Right now, we are facing an issue: when we browse the website for the first time the Marketo form is loading properly and submitted successfully but after the first submission the Marketo form does not show up agian. We are using WordPress for our website.

We are using this Marketo js: `//app-sj17.marketo.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.min.js`

Loading form as follows:

```
MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-sj17.marketo.com", "025-WCE-875", 1000, function(form) {
    // Add an onSuccess handler
});
```

Putting it inside : `<form id="mktoForm_1000" style="display:none;"></form>`

Any help will be valuable.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the form editor there is a setting that affects this behaviour.
Go to the *Settings* tab in the form editor and look for the “**If Known Visitor, Show**” setting. Make sure that you have the “Form” option selected as opposed to the Custom HTML”. Please see the screenshot below.

Explanation: before the first form fillout your visitor is unknown, so the form is shown every time. However, after the form submission your visitor will be known, thus if you have this setting enabled, the form will be hidden afterwards.

[image: Marketo Form Settings dialog]

Comment: Hi Amit, did this help you at the end?